# wilson's adjustment for sample proportion

Tags: proportion, sample

Could somebody provide a derivation for Wilson's adjustment for the CI of a sample proportion? The formula is:

$$\tilde{p} \approx \frac{x+2}{n+4}$$

where $x$ is the number of successes, and $n$ is the sample size.

Specifically, I want to know: **where do the 2 and the 4 come from?** Those numbers seem a bit arbitrary to me, and I've had no luck with Google.

Just trying to scratch my curiosity here...

Answer (score 7):

To my understanding the Wilson estimate is the center of [the Wilson interval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Wilson_score_interval), which gives
the estimate

$$\tilde{p}=\frac{\hat p + \frac{1}{2n} z^2}{1 + \frac{1}{n}  z^2}=\frac{X+ \frac{1}{2} z^2}{n + z^2}\,.$$

It is also the center of the [Agresti-Coull interval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Agresti-Coull_Interval).

If you take $\,\alpha=0.05\ $ and round 1.96 to 2, that gives the $\frac{X+2}{n+4}$ ("add 2 to both the successes and the failures") which is specifically mentioned in Agresti And Coull's paper, but rounding 1.96 to 2 is so often done that I'd be surprised if some people weren't using it since Wilson's paper appeared.

---

Wilson, E. B. (1927),
"Probable inference, the law of succession, and statistical inference,"
*Journal of the American Statistical Association* **22**,  209–212.

Agresti, Alan; Coull, Brent A. (1998),
"Approximate is better than 'exact' for interval estimation of binomial proportions,"
*The American Statistician* **52**: 119–126.
(This is at the first author's web pages [here](http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~aa/articles/agresti_coull_1998.pdf).)

Both papers are quite relevant.